# Terminal with output scrolling down

Tags: command-line

I have currently decided to test my double monitors in the vertical configuration, and I came across a problem that I had never had before:  the input line on my terminal is too far down the screen!

I was wondering if there is a way to make the output scroll downwards, so that the input line stays at the top.

e.g., a normal terminal view looks like this:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=28.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=46 time=19.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=45 time=20.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=5 ttl=45 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=6 ttl=46 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=7 ttl=46 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=8 ttl=45 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=9 ttl=45 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=10 ttl=45 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=11 ttl=45 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=12 ttl=45 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=13 ttl=45 time=20.0 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12017ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.773/17.391/28.343/3.812 ms
me@my_computer:~$
```

and instead I would like to have something like this:

```
me@my_computer:~$ 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.773/17.391/28.343/3.812 ms
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12017ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
^C
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=13 ttl=45 time=20.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=12 ttl=45 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=11 ttl=45 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=10 ttl=45 time=15.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=9 ttl=45 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=8 ttl=45 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=7 ttl=46 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=6 ttl=46 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=5 ttl=45 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=45 time=20.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=46 time=19.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=28.3 ms
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I could not find any such documentation or question on the forums. If anyone has an idea, please let me know! (also if you think it's not possible)

Thanks!

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one nice tip from which you can start. You must to play with bash:

> To set it up:
>
> ```
> $ bash    # try this in a subshell since ^C seems to cause it to exit
> $ f () { sed "1s/^/$(tput cup 0 0)/;s/^/$(tput il1)/"; }
> $ PROMPT_COMMAND='tput cup 0 0;tput il1; echo'
> $ exec > >(f)
> ```
>
> Press enter one extra time and it's ready to try. Sometimes the output
>   and the prompt are out of order and there may be other weirdness, but
>   it's kind of an interesting thing to try.

Source: [Reversed Terminal / Command line window](https://superuser.com/q/209394/221259).

See also:

- [Reverse bash console text flow](https://serverfault.com/q/152310/181186)
- [Pushdown Terminal Output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35627/37944)

Comment: i think it is just as my answer

Comment: @nux You think, but is not. It's [Dennis Williamson](http://superuser.com/users/310/dennis-williamson)'s answer, as I specified in my source ;)

Comment: ok never mind , i edit it so @cd can copy and paste in his terminal to test what it can do .

Comment: I had to accept this answer indeed due to the reference! But thanks nux too!

Answer (score 4):

After searching for this good question , i found this commands and hope it can help you , so it can help you focusing on the top of the terminal when writing a command .

In terminal try :

```
 f () { sed "1s/^/$(tput cup 0 0)/;s/^/$(tput il1)/"; }
 PROMPT_COMMAND='tput cup 0 0;tput il1; echo'
 exec > >(f)
```

Reference [Site](https://superuser.com/questions/209394/reversed-terminal-command-line-window)

Answer (score 4):

Another trick would be to pass your command's output through `tac` which is like `cat` but prints in reverse order:

```
terdon@oregano ~ $ ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 | tac
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 88.906/91.678/94.948/2.129 ms
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=42 time=88.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=42 time=92.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=90.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=91.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=94.9 ms
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Note that I had to specify a maximum ping number (`-c 5`) because otherwise the `ping` command won't exit and the pipe will break. Anyway, `tac` is very useful for this type of thing.

Comment: I like the tac - didn't know about it.  Unfortunately as you said yourself, it has some limitations.  And it does not set the command line to the top of the shell!

Comment: @cd127 no it doesn't, I hadn't realized you also wanted to move the prompt.