# Terminal commands from top to bottom

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to have a command line at the top of terminal and history moving down. Is it possible? I am using Ubuntu 16.04, gnome-terminal+tmux.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/431873/terminal-with-output-scrolling-down

Comment: what do you mean by 'history moving down'?